# How to get NULL as values for invalid column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms-2012

I'm using Sql Server 2012. Consider the table schema to be,

```
create table A (col1 int, col2 int)
```

I'm trying to execute this query,

`select col1, col2, col3, col4 from A`

I get execution error as `col3` and `col4` are not in table.

But is there any way, these 2 columns can be displayed in result with `NULL` as value for every row, even though it's not available in the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an alias for each one of these 2 columns:

```
select col1, col2, null as col3, null as col4 from A
```

Answer (score 4):

Try below select query..

```
select col1, col2, null as col3, null as col4 from A
```

Answer (score 2):

Cast Null as desired data type:

`select col1, col2, cast(null as int) as col3, cast(null as int) as col4 from A`